# Is it possible to skip "<service> started" entries from Samba logs?

Tags: debian, logs, samba

I have just installed and configure SAMBA on my Raspberry under Raspbian Bookworm.

I have noticed that there are many log entries like:

```
rpcd_mdssvc version 4.17.12-Debian started.
smbd version 4.17.12-Debian started.
```

and so on. I would like for the system to log only errors or abnormal behavior. Is there a way to get rid of these "started" logs?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `LogLevelMax` value in your samba systemd service.

```
LogLevelMax=2 # or 3
```

Here is the possible values from `man 2 syslog`:

```
   Kernel constant   Level value   Meaning
   KERN_EMERG             0        System is unusable
   KERN_ALERT             1        Action must be taken immediately
   KERN_CRIT              2        Critical conditions
   KERN_ERR               3        Error conditions
   KERN_WARNING           4        Warning conditions
   KERN_NOTICE            5        Normal but significant condition
   KERN_INFO              6        Informational
   KERN_DEBUG             7        Debug-level messages
```

Comment: Actually it does not seem to work. I have edited "/lib/systemd/system/smb.service" and added under [Service] LogLevelMax=2.
Then I have reloaded systemd with "sudo systemctl daemon-reload" and then restarted the Samba service with "sudo systemctl restart smbd". Please advise, thanks